# Bigcommerce using multiple filters with cURL

Tags: curl, filter, bigcommerce

Is it possible to use multiple filters with a curl request? For example,
`curl -s --request GET -u "apiusername":"apikey" https://store.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/orders.json?min_date_created=date&status_id=11`

This obviously doesn't work, since it won't read past the date; the idea being able to filter out just certain order statuses from the list of outputs rather than having to get the entire list and filter afterwards.

Thanks for any assistance.

-Edward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put single quotes around the URL when using an ampersand in order to stack multiple query parameters.

Comment: Thanks so much! This works exactly as I wanted. You're a lifesaver.